# I am working on a dashboard where I ask for a date and query results for previous 30 days

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, redash

I am working on a dashboard where I ask for a date and query results for previous 30 days. I am trying to use the dateadd function but it is throwing the error `month cannot be resolved`.

Here the end date part is parameterized. I am not a pro at this so it would be great if someone could resolve this. Doing this in redash using athena db.

```
SELECT  
COUNT event_name 
FROM master_event
WHERE
    CAST(date_parse(server_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') AS DATE)<= CAST ('{{ End Date }}' AS DATE)
    AND
    CAST(date_parse(server_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') AS DATE)>= dateadd(month,-1,'{{ End Date }}')
```

Comment: Did you try using `dateadd('m',-1,'{{ End Date }}')`? See if this works.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is redshift function even other DBS also support but not athena.
Another thing month needs to be in quotes as it is treating it as column name
Refer below example.

```
    select date_add('month',-1,current_date);
```